# Processing related csv files in Expression evaluator

Tags: csv, logic, expression, limit

We are trying to use an expression evaluator with limited coding capabilities to perform database operations on several files. The code looks like the following:

```
For each Shift record in shifts table
    If shift.qualification matches 'qualification of user' in qualifications table THEN
       If shift.ward matches 'ward of user' in preferredWards table THEN
           If shift.StartTime does not match 'Booked shifts of user' in transaction table THEN
                Print Shift.Id, Shift.Date, Shift.StartTime
           End IF
       End IF
    End IF
Next
```

The above code works to the extent that it pulls all the records from the shifts table. There are two problems which we are unable to solve and need help with:

1. We cannot limit the number or records printed (Framework does not permit break statements or loop counting variables)
2. We cannot determine if the code printed nothing because none of the shift records meet the criteria

Please note that this is a Framework-dependent problem and hence the limitations mentioned above cannot be overcome. It is not possible to do basic things like creating arrays, variables or breaking the for loop.

This is a logic problem more than anything else and I was hoping someone could help come up with a logic that allows us to do the following:

1. Get all the shift records that meet the conditions
2. Limit the records to 10
3. Somehow indicate if there are no records found with those conditions

Appreciate any help I can get

Comment: Not sure I get why you are using a 'framework' that does not allow you to even create a variable, but in such a case, I would get the output file and manipulate the results via another program written in another language.

Comment: Unfortunately, using another program is not an option ... I was wondering if I can start an outer for loop with one of the other tables and go through the shifts last, but that logic is not standard and I'm not able to crack it ... So was hoping that someone could help determine another way with the constraints (We all have constraints :()

Comment: I can add a 'Max=10' in the for loop, but that only ends up looping 10 times as opposed to printing 10 records... So that isn't solving it either

Comment: I can't think of a way out in this case.